# How to capture pc sound and send it via sockets using java

Tags: java, audio, audio-capture

I am trying to capture audio from pc(from speaker/headphones) and send it via socket(UDP, if possible) to another computer, which must play it back. I have found some code to do this:

Server:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    ServerSocket MyService;
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    InputStream input;
    AudioFormat audioFormat;
    SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;
    byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[10000];
    static Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();

    Server() throws LineUnavailableException {

        try {
            Mixer mixer_ = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[0]);
            audioFormat = getAudioFormat();
            DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
            sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
            sourceDataLine.open(audioFormat);
            sourceDataLine.start();
            MyService = new ServerSocket(500);
            clientSocket = MyService.accept();

            input = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            while (input.read(tempBuffer) != -1) {
                sourceDataLine.write(tempBuffer, 0, 10000);

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
        float sampleRate = 8000.0F;
        int sampleSizeInBits = 8;
        int channels = 1;
        boolean signed = true;
        boolean bigEndian = false;
        return new AudioFormat(
                sampleRate,
                sampleSizeInBits,
                channels,
                signed,
                bigEndian);
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) throws LineUnavailableException {
        Server s2 = new Server();
    }}
```

Client:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
    boolean stopCapture = false;
    AudioFormat audioFormat;
    TargetDataLine targetDataLine;
    BufferedOutputStream out = null;
    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    Socket sock = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client tx = new Client();
        tx.captureAudio();
    }
    private void captureAudio() {
        try {
            sock = new Socket("192.168.1.38", 500);
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
            in = new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
            Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
            audioFormat = getAudioFormat();
            DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(
                    TargetDataLine.class, audioFormat);
            Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[2]);

            targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) mixer.getLine(dataLineInfo);
            targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
            targetDataLine.start();

            Thread captureThread = new CaptureThread();
            captureThread.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    class CaptureThread extends Thread {

        byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[10000];

        @Override
        public void run() {
            stopCapture = false;
            try {
                while (!stopCapture) {
                    int cnt = targetDataLine.read(tempBuffer, 0,
                            tempBuffer.length);
                    out.write(tempBuffer);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    private AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
        float sampleRate = 8000.0F;

        int sampleSizeInBits = 8;

        int channels = 1;

        boolean signed = true;

        boolean bigEndian = false;

        return new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed,
                bigEndian);
    }}
```

But client throws

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Line unsupported: interface TargetDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 8000.0 Hz, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice.getLine(DirectAudioDevice.java:175)
    at Client.captureAudio(Client.java:28)
    at Client.main(Client.java:15)
```

and i do not know what to do(I know it is not UDP socket, but i firstly want to have some code which work). Advance thanks.

Comment: I'm in a bit over my head, but the current hitch could be that the format you specify isn't supported on the client. You might give AudioSystem.getAudioFileTypes(AudioInputStream) a look to help investigate the error message. Returns an array of AudioFileFormat.Type instances.

Comment: @phil-freihofner sorry, but i did not understand what the AudioInputStream should i give as a parameter?

Comment: As I said, I'm in over my head. Getting AudioFileTypes doesn't turn out to be particularly helpful. Apologies! But you could check the following
AudioSystem.isLineSupported(dataLineInfo);
Also, if the above returns true, try TargetDataLine tdl = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);  
Do you have a reason for choosing a line from MixerInfo[2]? Often we can get what we need from the default Mixer by using AudioSystem's getLine method.